# Mustachejs various objects in view

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have an object with array of data in {}, I want to print name attribute of all params.

The object is:

```
[

 {
  "name": "Chris",
  "value": 10000,
  "taxed_value": 10000 - (10000 * 0.4),
  "in_ca": true
 },

 {
  "name": "Estafanie",
  "value": 14000,
  "taxed_value": 10000 - (10000 * 0.4),
  "in_ca": true
 },

 {
  "name": "Paul",
  "value": 20000,
  "taxed_value": 10000 - (10000 * 0.4),
  "in_ca": true
 }
]
```

I want to see in my html:

```
Chris, Estefanie, Paul
```

I try with:

```
{{# _.each(name, function(listname){ }}
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="names">
          <h5>{{{ listname }}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{# }) }}
```

But not working ;/ I find in mustache documentation but I don't see nothing same.

Anybody can help me with this?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view doesn't look like a MustacheJS view. Amend it to look like the following. Substitute "ObjectLiteralName" for the name of your object literal variable name.

Using `{{#}}{{/}}` in a Mustache view denotes that you wish to loop over an object.

See [MustacheJS](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js). It contains all the information you need to get up and running with Mustache.

**View**

```
<div id="target">Loading...</div>
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
   {{#ObjectLiteralName}}
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="names">
       {{name}}
      </div>
   </div>
   {{/ObjectLiteralName}}
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
function renderTemplate() {
  var $template = $('#template').html();
  Mustache.parse($template);   // optional, speeds up future uses
  var rendered = Mustache.render($template, ObjectLiteralName);
  $('#target').html(rendered);
}
```

**Result**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <div class="names">
     Chris
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <div class="names">
     Estefanie
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <div class="names">
     Paul
  </div>
</div>
```